# TokenMismatchException Laravel By loading old csrf token from Caching

Tags: laravel, caching

I am having trouble with an AJAX POST request in Laravel. when access my site first time, it's get older CSRF token from cache.
When i reload the site again, its get correct token. How can i solve this?

Comment: My first guess is maybe your **csrf_field()** is outside of your form element in which every time you submit, the csrf stays the same.

Comment: did u find solution?

Answer (score 0):

Put your token that way to ajax request:

```
data: {
        "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
        "id": id
        }
```

Or set token in header:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

and then:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
</script>
```

Good luck!